# LNCS proceedings template Command \proof already defined

Tags: amsmath, theorems, amsthm, journal

Trying to put my paper into LNCS format and I don't know what the source of the error here is

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[algosection,ruled,lined,linesnumbered,longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\begin{document}
\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}
\maketitle              
\begin{abstract}
The abstract 
\end{abstract}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection Sample}
Please note 
\end{document}
```

LNCS file available here https://www.overleaf.com/read/ygfkzwkxjhbw#d20610

Comment: Insert `\let\proof\relax \let\endproof\relax` before `\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}`.

Comment: @Mico That gives me a  missing \begin{document}  error.

Comment: I get no such error message. Check if you've inserted a different command that tries to typeset something.

Comment: @Mico Ah my mistake I leftout the second relax

Answer (score 4):

The `llncs` class has its own way to define theorem-like environments and doesn't like to be called together with `amsmath`.

It already defines a `proof` environment, namely

```
\spnewtheorem*{proof}{Proof}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
```

In a quite contrived way, this ensures that if `\proofname` is defined (possibly by a language definition file), it is used for labeling the proof.

Springer's house style seems to be of not generally adding a QED symbol; I checked Lang's “Algebra” and Hartshorne's “Algebraic Geometry”, which haven't QED symbols; to the contrary, Massey's “Singular Homology Theory” has <sub><sup>Q.E.D.</sup></sub> at the end of the line.

My suggestion is to load `amsthm` just for its `proof` environment and to *not* load `thmtools`, but to rely on Springer's `\spnewtheorem` command for defining your theorem-like environment (or using the predefined ones)

```
theorem case conjecture corollary definition example exercise
lemma note problem property proposition question solution remark
```

Load `amsthm` last and don't load `thmtools`.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[algosection,ruled,lined,linesnumbered,longend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
The abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection Sample}
Please note

\begin{proof}
abc
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the OP wants to use the `cleveref` package to create cross-references to theorem-like environments, `amsthm` should be loaded *before* `cleveref`. (This may or may not be relevant if the OP ends up using the `\spnewtheorem` machinery.)

Comment: @Mico My experiment shows that `\spnewtheorem` defined environments work out of the box with `cleveref`. I wanted to say that `\newtheorem` should *not* be used within `llncs`. The only part used of `amsthm` is `proof` that has no relationship with `cleveref`.